# Elasticlunr search to return document object based on the index

Tags: javascript

the `elasticlunr.js` search configuration as follows,

```
var index = elasticlunr(function () {
  this.addField('title');
  this.addField('body');
  this.setRef('id');
});

var doc1 = {
  "id": '1',
  "title": "Oracle released its latest database Oracle 12g beta",
  "body": "Yestaday Oracle has released its new database Oracle 12g, this would make more money for this company and lead to a nice profit report of annual year."
}

var doc2 = {
  "id": '2',
  "title": "Oracle released its profit report of 2015",
  "body": "As expected, Oracle released its profit report of 2015, during the good sales of database and hardware, Oracle's profit of 2015 reached 12.5 Billion."
}

index.addDoc(doc1);
index.addDoc(doc2);

let result = index.search("beta");
```

It returns,

> [{"ref":"1","score":0.3779644730092272}]

This [elasticlunr document](http://elasticlunr.com/docs/document_store.js.html) says it is storing the document on index.

 Then how come i get stored document from that perticular index ?

Am looking to get my original document as a search results ?
ie.

```
[{
      "id": '1',
      "title": "Oracle released its latest database Oracle 12g beta",
      "body": "Yestaday Oracle has released its new database Oracle 12g, this would make more money for this company and lead to a nice profit report of annual year."
    }]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from the `documentStore` in the `index`. So after you get the result, use the `id` to get the doc from the store:

```
index.documentStore.getDoc('1')
```

Comment: it's probably better to use .`getDoc('1')` method instead of `.docs['1']`

Comment: Note: you need to set `index.saveDocument(true)` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm storing my documents in an array, referenced by indexes. 
When I add a document to elasticlunr, the id I use refers to one of the positions in the array. 
That way, when I get a set of results, I use the id to lookup the relevant document in my array.

Comment: Yes.. i did this bit earlier.. the problem is i need to update my index and the Object in Array as well. it would be harder to manage. also from storage perspective i need to store `lunr index object` and the `whole object in array`